# Forcing sequential execution in nodejs

Tags: node.js

I am supplied with three functions in nodejs. It is given below.

I am allowed to change the code only in the placeholder  and nowhere in the function.
The three function always need to get executed only in a particular order say
function 1 then function 2 then function 3.

Can anyone help!

====================================

```
const util = require('util');

//Write some code below this

//Write some code above this

function function1(result){
    n=Math.floor(Math.random() * 500);
    setTimeout(()=>{
    console.log("Finished Waiting in Step 1 after time out of -"+n+"\n\n");
  },n) ;
}

function function2(result){
    m=Math.floor(Math.random() * 500);
    setTimeout(()=>{
    console.log("Finished Waiting in Step 2 after time out of -"+m+"\n\n");
  },m) ;

}

function function3(result){
  console.log("finished executing step 3"+ "\n\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is right approach. But you can simply redefine

```
setTimeout = (cb)=> {cb()}
///Now these executes in sequence...
function1();
function2();
function3();
```

//Here is a good article to read of setTimeout
https://levelup.gitconnected.com/understanding-settimeout-15c7de9e5fd6

Comment: Thank you, Bipin!

Comment: Thank you, Bipin! and you are right, this approach may not work for all scenarios where third party licensed functions are supplied and we are not in a position to change them. If the third party functions would have included read files using readFile method instead of timeout, this solution would not work. Not sure what would be that approach, that will work for all scenario in terms of forcing sequential execution of any set of functions! Anyway, thank you for your effort!

Comment: Sure. Though?what do you want to achieve by doing this.

Comment: I have to deal with multiple third party licensed modules. Trying to figure out a generic way, in which any set of functions can be made to be executed in any particular order.